# Getting 404 on laravel 5.7 when ssl enabled

Tags: laravel, ssl, namecheap

I have installed laravel 5.7 app in namecheap shared hosting. App loads with http://. But when i use https:// i am getting 404.

When i tested, the app is reaching index.php file. something is not working from there.

Everything is default. .htaccess file, routes and everything. It is a fresh install of laravel.

Please help me to fix getting 404 when ssl is enabled.

Comment: share your .htaccess code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put your app into private_html after enabling ssl.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but didnt work.  here is what i did, created a folder called laravel in home directory. put all laravel files there. files in public folder copied to public_html file. and edited public_html/index.php paths to use laravel folder inside home dir.

Comment: `unregistering my service worker` ? Please elaborate @VishK

Comment: I am using service worker. For some reason the route was not loading. Page loaded well once when I unregisted service worker. Next reload stoped working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this rules before your default rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Further check if you actually have an ssl certificate installed, it shouldn't cause this error, but you should still check it.